# Editable Settings in Custom WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, single-page-application, singlepage, underscores-wp

I am trying to implement a simple one page -no blog- WordPress theme using a bootstrap template. I have an aside with three social links -facebook, twitter, Instagram- in the header.

I want to be able to make it so not only are these able to put truned on or off in by the user through the wp admin dashboard, but also the links to those sites able to be put in through said dashboard.

I am using udnerscores as a starter theme. How do I go about doing what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [Customizer API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API). That would be my recommendation. There is a lot of really good documentation on how to use that [here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) It also includes a whole bunch of sample code. Give that a look.